# Horizontally scroll images which has transform effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, deployment

I am trying to creating a horizontal image gallery with scrolling functionality and when hovered over an image, it first removes the grayscale and then has a transformation effect. And when each image is clicked it displays full image in new window.

But issue is if there are more images than what the browser window can display, other images are flown out of the window and the scroll option is not working. Can you please help me out here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8X9e.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkKT8.png)

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Scrollable Image Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "dock">
        <div class = "dock-item">
            <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/965/883/624/manga-one-piece-wallpaper-preview.jpg" alt="Northern Lights, Norway">
        </div>
        <div class = "dock-item">
            <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/114/1008/41/one-piece-monkey-d-luffy-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg" alt="Zoro">
        </div>
        <!-- 14 more such images are here, had to trim -->
    </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="modalImage">
    <div id="caption"></div>
</div>


<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0 auto 2em auto;
    padding: 1em 0.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transform-origin: center;
}

.container img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 350px;
    object-fit: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.container img:hover{
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.dock {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    width: calc(80px * 17 + 10px * 16);
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}

.dock::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}

.dock-item {
    width: 80px;
    height: 350px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 700ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.02, 0.165, 1);
    transform-origin: center;
}

#myModal {
  z-index: 101; /* Set a value higher than the navbar's z-index */
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

.modal-content, #caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover, .close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
const dockContainer = document.querySelector('.dock');
const dockItems = document.querySelectorAll('.dock-item');

const defaultItemScale = 1;
const hoverItemScale = 1.5; // Larger scale for hovered image
const neighbourItemScale = 1.2; // Slightly larger scale for neighbor images

const defaultMargin = "5px";
const expandMargin = "10px";

const updateDockItems = (hoveredItemIndex) => {
  dockItems.forEach((item, index) => {
    let scale = defaultItemScale;
    let margin = defaultMargin;

    if (index === hoveredItemIndex) {
      scale = hoverItemScale;
      margin = expandMargin;
    } else if (Math.abs(index - hoveredItemIndex) === 1) {
      scale = neighbourItemScale;
      margin = expandMargin;
    }

    item.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
    item.style.margin = `0 ${margin}`;
  });
};

dockItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    updateDockItems(index);
  });
});

dockContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  resetDockItems();
});

// Function to reset all dock items to default state
const resetDockItems = () => {
  dockItems.forEach((item) => {
    item.style.transform = "";
    item.style.margin = "";
  });
};

var images = document.querySelectorAll('.dock-item img');
console.log(images);
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modalImg = document.getElementById('modalImage');
var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');

var scrollPosition = 0;
var imageIndex = 0; // Track the index of the centered image

function openModal(src, alt) {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
  modalImg.src = src;
  captionText.innerHTML = alt;
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

images.forEach(function (img, index) {
  img.onload = function () { // Wait for the image to load
    updateImagePositions(); // Update image positions after the image has loaded
  };
  
  img.onclick = function () {
    openModal(this.src, this.alt);
    imageIndex = index;
  };
});

// Add event listener for scroll wheel and trackpad
dockContainer.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
  // Calculate the new scroll position based on the wheel event
  scrollPosition += e.deltaY;

  // Ensure scrollPosition stays within bounds
  scrollPosition = Math.min(dockContainer.scrollWidth - dockContainer.clientWidth, Math.max(0, scrollPosition));

  // Set the new scroll position
  dockContainer.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;

  // Update the centered image index
  imageIndex = Math.round(scrollPosition / images[0].offsetWidth);

  // Prevent the default scroll behavior
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Add event listener for trackpad (for some browsers)
dockContainer.addEventListener('mousewheel', function (e) {
  // Calculate the new scroll position based on the wheel event
  scrollPosition += e.deltaY;

  // Ensure scrollPosition stays within bounds
  scrollPosition = Math.min(dockContainer.scrollWidth - dockContainer.clientWidth, Math.max(0, scrollPosition));

  // Set the new scroll position
  dockContainer.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;

  // Update the centered image index
  imageIndex = Math.round(scrollPosition / images[0].offsetWidth);

  // Prevent the default scroll behavior
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Update image positions when the window is resized
window.addEventListener('resize', updateImagePositions);

// Function to update image positions based on the centered image
function updateImagePositions() {
  const centerIndex = Math.floor(images.length / 2);

  // Calculate the scroll position based on the centered image
  scrollPosition = centerIndex * images[0].offsetWidth - dockContainer.offsetWidth / 2;

  // Ensure scrollPosition stays within bounds
  scrollPosition = Math.min(dockContainer.scrollWidth - dockContainer.clientWidth, Math.max(0, scrollPosition));

  // Set the new scroll position
  dockContainer.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;

  // Update the centered image index
  imageIndex = centerIndex;
}

// Initially center the images
updateImagePositions();
```

Thanks in advance for taking your time to answer this!!
Please feel free to let me know if there is anything that is redundant or not required!

Initially My idea was to get image effects similar to this website (https://aristidebenoist.com/).
But since I am not proficient in CSS/JS I just wanted to have a horizontally image gallery which has scrolling functionality and has some transformation/effect when hovered.

Answer (score 1):

`overflow-x: scroll` should be added to your container, not items.

Ex:

```css
.container {
  height: 180px;
  /* horizontal align */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* horizontal scroll */
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.container > div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 40px;
    background: lightgray;
    margin: 0 5px;
    /* don't shrink */
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

P.S. I'm new here, too. So my answer may not be the best ;)

**Edited:**

Maybe this will work for you:

```js
const dockContainer = document.querySelector('.dock');
const dockItems = document.querySelectorAll('.dock-item');

const defaultItemScale = 1;
const hoverItemScale = 1.5; // Larger scale for hovered image
const neighbourItemScale = 1.2; // Slightly larger scale for neighbor images

const defaultMargin = "5px";
const expandMargin = "10px";

const updateDockItems = (hoveredItemIndex) => {
  dockItems.forEach((item, index) => {
    let scale = defaultItemScale;
    let margin = defaultMargin;

    if (index === hoveredItemIndex) {
      scale = hoverItemScale;
      margin = expandMargin;
    } else if (Math.abs(index - hoveredItemIndex) === 1) {
      scale = neighbourItemScale;
      margin = expandMargin;
    }

    item.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
    item.style.margin = `0 ${margin}`;
  });
};

dockItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    updateDockItems(index);
  });
});

dockContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  resetDockItems();
});

// Function to reset all dock items to default state
const resetDockItems = () => {
  dockItems.forEach((item) => {
    item.style.transform = "";
    item.style.margin = "";
  });
};

var images = document.querySelectorAll('.dock-item img');
// console.log(images);
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modalImg = document.getElementById('modalImage');
var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');

var scrollPosition = 0;
var imageIndex = 0; // Track the index of the centered image

function openModal(src, alt) {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
  modalImg.src = src;
  captionText.innerHTML = alt;
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

images.forEach(function (img, index) {
  img.onload = function () { // Wait for the image to load
    updateImagePositions(); // Update image positions after the image has loaded
  };
  
  img.onclick = function () {
    openModal(this.src, this.alt);
    imageIndex = index;
  };
});

// Add event listener for scroll wheel and trackpad
dockContainer.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
  // Calculate the new scroll position based on the wheel event
  scrollPosition += e.deltaY;

  // Ensure scrollPosition stays within bounds
  scrollPosition = Math.min(dockContainer.scrollWidth - dockContainer.clientWidth, Math.max(0, scrollPosition));

  // Set the new scroll position
  dockContainer.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;

  // Update the centered image index
  imageIndex = Math.round(scrollPosition / images[0].offsetWidth);

  // Prevent the default scroll behavior
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Add event listener for trackpad (for some browsers)
dockContainer.addEventListener('mousewheel', function (e) {
  // Calculate the new scroll position based on the wheel event
  scrollPosition += e.deltaY;

  // Ensure scrollPosition stays within bounds
  scrollPosition = Math.min(dockContainer.scrollWidth - dockContainer.clientWidth, Math.max(0, scrollPosition));

  // Set the new scroll position
  dockContainer.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;

  // Update the centered image index
  imageIndex = Math.round(scrollPosition / images[0].offsetWidth);

  // Prevent the default scroll behavior
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Update image positions when the window is resized
window.addEventListener('resize', updateImagePositions);

// Function to update image positions based on the centered image
function updateImagePositions() {
  const centerIndex = Math.floor(images.length / 2);

  // Calculate the scroll position based on the centered image
  scrollPosition = centerIndex * images[0].offsetWidth - dockContainer.offsetWidth / 2;

  // Ensure scrollPosition stays within bounds
  scrollPosition = Math.min(dockContainer.scrollWidth - dockContainer.clientWidth, Math.max(0, scrollPosition));

  // Set the new scroll position
  dockContainer.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;

  // Update the centered image index
  imageIndex = centerIndex;
}

// Initially center the images
updateImagePositions();
```

```css
/* HIGHLIGHT FIRST CHILD */
.dock > *:first-child {
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 8px solid red;
}
/* HIGHLIGHT LAST CHILD */
.dock > *:last-child {
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 8px solid blue;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden; /* IN CASE IT's BODY SCROLLING */
}

/* THE CONTAINER WHICH IS FIXED, AND HAVE SCROLLBAR */
.outer-container {
    height: 40em;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* VERTICALLY CENTERED */
    overflow-x: scroll; /* THIS MAKES IT SCROLL */
}

/* THE CONTAINER WHICH REALLY CONTAINS IMAGES */
.container {
    margin: 0 auto 2em auto;
    padding: 3em 2em; /* I CHANGED THIS BIGGER, SO IT LOOKS BETTER */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start; /* THIS SHOULD NOT BE CENTER */
    transform-origin: center;
}

.container img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 350px;
    object-fit: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.container img:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.dock {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;
    /* Firefox */
}

.dock::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
}

.dock-item {
    width: 80px;
    height: 350px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 700ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.02, 0.165, 1);
    transform-origin: center;
}

#myModal {
    z-index: 101;
    /* Set a value higher than the navbar's z-index */
}

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

.modal-content,
#caption {
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />

<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="dock">
            <!-- IMAGE WILL APPEND HERE -->
        </div>
        <script>
            // GENERATE THOSE IMAGE FOR TEST
            // USE YOUR OWN IMAGES INSIDE ".dock"
            const dockElement = document.querySelector(".dock");
            for (let i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
                dockElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
                    <div class="dock-item">
                        <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/965/883/624/manga-one-piece-wallpaper-preview.jpg"
                            alt="Northern Lights, Norway">
                    </div>
                `);
        </script>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="modalImage">
    <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

Now all images are contained correctly.

But I still don't know how to make it auto scroll on mousewheel.
And it seems whenever you hover on it, your targeted image will shift a bit because the margin changed :I

By the way, do you know `<canvas>`? maybe you can use that istead of raw HTML, CSS & JS

Comment: Hey @star_huey,
Thanks you for taking your time in answering. 
The there are 2 issues here 

1. I want it be able to scroll the horizontally image gallery using my scroller instead of using the scroll bar at the bottom. (trackpad incase of laptop)

2. When I run this with the transformation effect, it still misses few images and I am not able to scroll to those images via scroll bar as well.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, now at least i am able to see the first image.
I do have very basic understanding on <canvas>, let me check that out and see if I can use that here.
Thank you!